# How is Fight For Your Life time determined?

Tags: borderlands-2

The teammate revive timer appears to move faster than usual sometimes. Am I imagining this?How does the bleed-out/revive/cripple time change, and what affects it? Does it quicken with your level/experience? Or when playing in groups outside your ideal level range? The number of co-op players in a game? As a penalty for repeatedly dying?

Also, how many seconds is it, and how does that change?

Answer (score 3):

Fight for your life time reduces each time you use it during a single 'fight'. It appears to reset once there are no aggroed enemies near you, or when you respawn at a New U.

Bleed-out time can be increased with artifacts, shield mods and some team-level bonuses. The number of players in the team won't affect it, but the number equipping [Veritas](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Veritas) gun or [Aequitas](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Aequitas) shield will.

Player level and relative co-op level have no effect.

Comment: I think it's based on time not aggro. I've noticed in prolonged fights it seems to stay long if I go a fair amount of times between deaths.

Comment: @BenBrocka yeah that is true. You can even notice this, (not easily) die a few times quickly, watch the counter go past very very quick. Then run around a bit, and the timer will be longer again. At least it was in my limited tests.

Comment: I suspect that there's some other variable (perhaps how far negative your HP went when killed?).  I've had some fights where I hadn't been in one for hours, and the timer went *much* faster than normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are several relics that change this as far as I know. Also the amount of time between 'deaths' is also a factor. So if you get a second wind, and get killed again, [the bleed out time is reduced](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Crippled#Second_Wind). At least this was the case in borderlands 1. And I assume this is the same thing see in borderlands 2.